# how would I send a value from static function to the other object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, plugins, static

```js
  (function ($, window, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    class Slider {

      static init(loop) {
        Slider.loop = loop;
        return Slider.loop;
      }

    };
    $.fn.blueSlider = function(loop, options) {
      var defaults = {

      }
      var loop = Slider.init(loop);
      console.log(loop);
      $.extend(defaults, options);
    };
  }(jQuery))

  $('div').blueSlider(true);
```

```html
<div></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm new at making the code using `class function` so please excuse about any other mistakes that I hasn't mentioned in the question.

I'm trying to combine `class function` and jQuery Plugin. This line:  `$.fn.blueSlider = function(loop, options)`, the jQuery initialize function has 2 parameters and the `loop` parameter is actually `Slider.init()`'s parameter. So I have to declare a new variable some kind like this `var loop = Slider.init(loop);` for accessing the `loop` value.

My expectation is to put the `loop` parameter inside of the `options` so it can be called by the jQuery initialize method when I want to change the value of `loop` like this:

```
$(className).blueSlider({
  loop: false,
  // etc.
})
```

I've tried to create an object `options` and put it into the `loop` parameter for transfer the value to the other object but it didn't work:

```
$.fn.blueSlider = function(options) {
  var defaults = {

  }
  var options = {
    loop: Slider.init(loop),
  }
  $.extend(defaults, options);
};
```

Is there any ways to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use `class` syntax, you don't want to provide a custom `init` function; instead, provide a constructor and use `new`.

It's also important to remember that jQuery is *set-based*, meaning that `this` when you get called is a jQuery object containing a *set* of elements. In most cases, the appropriate thing for the plugin to do is act as though it had been called on each of those elements individually. For instance:

```js
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    
    // Moved defaults out of the function, added
    // more for the example
    const defaults = {
      someOption: "foo",
      someOtherOption: "bar",
      color: "green"
    };

    // The class
    class Slider {
        constructor(loop = true, options) {
            // Handle initialization in the constructor
            this.options = defaults;
            this.setOptions(loop, options);
        }
        setOptions(loop, options) {
            this.loop = loop;
            this.options = Object.assign({}, this.options, options);
            // In ES2017+, you could use:
            // this.options = {...defaults, ...this.options};
        }
        // Use a method to handle applying the slider to an element
        apply($el) {
            // ...do slider's thing on $el...
            $el.css("color", this.options.color);
            $el.text("loop = " + this.loop);
        }
    }

    $.fn.blueSlider = function(loop, options) {
        // Loop through the elements
        this.each(function() {
            // Create or reuse an instance for each element
            const $el = $(this);
            let slider = $el.data("blueSlider");
            if (slider) {
                // Element already has a slider
                slider.setOptions(loop, options);
            } else {
                // Create slider for element, remember it
                slider = new Slider(loop, options);
                $el.data("blueSlider", slider);
            }
            slider.apply($el);
        });
    };
}(jQuery))

$('div.a').blueSlider(true, {color: "blue"});
$('div.b').blueSlider(false);
setTimeout(() => {
  $('div.a:first').blueSlider(false);
}, 800);
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for great example. I've searched so long on google and github for trying to figure out how these are working.